# Login from Android app not working with a PHP/MySQL backend

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am actually making a login app but I am unable to login. Here is my mainactivity.java what could be I doing wrong ?

```
  ppublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText email, password;
private Button btn_login;
private ProgressBar loading;
private static String URL_LOGIN ="http://itsolutionsnepal.com/attendance/api/employeeLogin";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loading= findViewById(R.id.loading);
    email = findViewById(R.id.editTextUserEmail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);


    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String mPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPassword.isEmpty()) {
                Login(mEmail, mPassword);
            }else{
                email.setError("Please Enter Email");
                password.setError("Please Enter Password");

            }


        }
    });

}

private void Login(final String email, final String password) {
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = object.getString("_first_name").trim();
                            String email =  object.getString("_email").trim();

                            //  JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
//                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("");
                           //JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


//                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
//
//                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("");

                        //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                       // Log.d("JSON", jsonObject.toString());
                        //String success = jsonObject.getString("");
                       // JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");
                     //   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                       // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("");
                     //   String code = jsonObject.getString("");

  //                            if (success.equals("1"))
   //                            {

  //                                    String name = 
 object.getString("_first_name").trim();
//                                    String email = 
  object.getString("_email").trim();


 //                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
 "Success 
 Login \nYour name: "+name+"\nYour Email: "+email,
 //                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            System.out.println("Value of response - " + 
response);

                            System.out.println("First Name : " + name);
                            System.out.println("Email : " + email);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                            //}

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" +e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" +error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("_email", email);
            params.put("_password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Here is my json response
[image]

Here is my php code:

[image]

Here is my error log:

[image]

I am developing this for my college project. What is wrong with my code?

Edit: This is the full screen shot from postman

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the JSON string exception in your error log screenshot "java.lang.String cannot be..." [end of image]. I guess that line should give you a hint. And please do not post text as image (your php code), copy/paste the relevant parts.

Comment: I don't know android code very well, so I could be wrong, but I don't see anywhere in the Java code where you send the username and password to the server in the login request. You can use your PHP debug tools to verify that, potentially.

Comment: BTW md5 is not a secure way to hash your passwords any more. A brute force attack can guess the password without too much difficulty. PHP provides [special functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for doing this task correctly.

Comment: @Lookaji That says java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray" that's because in the PHP, in the error condition, it returns a simple string instead of a user object...but the PHP gives no indication that it's going to do that, so the Android code is trying to parse it as a user object. If there's an error, the server should return an error HTTP status code e.g. 403 Forbidden along with the message. Then the client (Android) can distinguish between success and error conditions without having to parse the message (which it can't because it doesn't know what structure it's going to have)

Comment: So there is an error in the php code?

Comment: @ADyson How should I do it then? Any solutions?

Comment: the log said MainActivity.java line 75 has json type exception. which line is line 75?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @ManishThapa my last comment contains the solution to the string error already.

Comment: @ADyson I cant fix it.. please help me out.

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand about what I wrote?

Comment: I dont know how to parse It as a string instead of an user object

Comment: @ADyson Help me out please

Comment: First you have to do what I said in the PHP and return a different HTTP status when it's an error. Otherwise you won't even know when is the right time to parse it as a string and when is the right time to parse it as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys in the volley request contradict with your POSTMAN screenshot. You are adding an underscore before the password and email, because of that you are getting a string response from your php code: `Login credential wrong please try again!`. I will advice you to add a status code to the response and parse according to the error

```
  @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
```

Also using MD5 is not [secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36117/how-secure-is-using-cram-md5-for-email-authentication-when-not-using-an-ssl-con)
[image]

Comment: The error is showing because you are getting that string `Login credential wrong please try again!` and I have checked on studio and it worked fine when I removed underscore

Comment: So what should I change can you help me out?

Comment: @ManishThapa remove the underscores from the getParams method's keys and try calling the func directly `Login("sndrawal18@hotmail.com", "password");` if it helped please mark the answer as correct

Comment: But I have too many user name and passwords in the backend .. i just dont want single username or password

Comment: And where should I call directly Login("sndrawal18@hotmail.com", "password");

Comment: I told this `Login("sndrawal18@hotmail.com", "password");` to verify that the code works when correct credentials are given. I didn't told you to hardcode it. Call it in the onCreate

Comment: I didnt get you ...can you please show me .. i would appreciate a lot thanku.

Comment: Please can u edit in my code and show me how can i actually do it.

Comment: whats the result you get when you put it on onCreate

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: How did u get that log ? How did u do it?